# Can you a query like this in SQL?

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have three tables:

```
tbl_customers
tbl_users
tbl_reviews
```

I have an application where, customer submit reviews for users. What I want to be able to do is not have multiple reviews of the same user from the same customer. This is what I want to do.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl_customers
WHERE
  tbl_customer.CustomerID != tbl_review.CustomerID
  AND tbl_user.UserID != tbl_reviews.UserID
```

- CustomerID is p_id for tbl_customer
- UserID is p_id for tbl_users.
- Foreign key relationship for both of them in tbl_review.

Thanks in advance.

If more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired o/p

Comment: do you want a query or db constraint for tbl_reviews like `unique (customer_id, user_id)`

Comment: Could you please be more precise in explaining the results you want? Do you want a full list of all of the users with only one customer review per user? Are you trying to prevent a customer from reviewing the same user multiple times? If not, I don't really see why you'd want to block out multiple reviews of that user from the same customer, as they may be valuable. They may have multiple interactions with that user and want to review him/her each time.

Comment: @FrankAllenby Yes I am trying to prevent a customer from reviewing the same user multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a unique constraint on your tbl_reviews table which uses both columns. This will disallow multiple entries altogether which will allow you to do a simple join. You will just have to add validation for when the entry is added so it doesn't error out when a user tries to enter more than one review for the same person.

```
alter table tbl_reviews add unique index(reviewid, userid);

select *
from tbl_users as u
join tbl_reviews as r on r.userid = u.userid
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the tbl_customer to ever have multiple reviews for the same tbl_user then you could create a unique index for tbl_review based on CustomerID and UserID. This would ensure that there is no possible way you would have two reviews with the same linkage.

Besides that you can do a simple count to see if a review already exists before posting:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_reviews WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID AND UserID = @UserID`

If you are saying that you want to have multiple reviews in the database but only select one from each customer then you would simply want to group by the customer ID and select the first/last review.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the idea of a unique constraint. I want to add that in SQL Server (and possibly other dbs) you can use a MERGE statement instead of an INSERT and it will either update the exisiting record or insert a new one. However, you may just want to check to see ifa review exists and if it does ask them if they want to update it. Do this before the person does more than just specify the user the review is on, so they can callup the existing review and make changes rather than rewrite everything.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM
tbl_users tu
 INNER JOIN 
tbl_reviews tr
ON tu.UserID=tr.UserID;
```

Comment: Don't use implied syntax. it is a SQL antipattern and we are trying to get people to learn the best techniques not the worst ones.